# package.json and remote git repository

Tags: git, github, npm, package, yarnpkg

In my `package.json` I have defined a `GitHub repo` as a dependency.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native": "0.54.0-rc.3",
    "react-native-maps": "https://github.com/Stophface/react-native-maps-0.20.1.git"
  },
```

I cloned this repo locally onto my computer, make changes in the code and push them to the repo. I then want the changes to reflect in my project. Therefore I delete the `node_modules` folder and then reinstall the `node_modules` with `yarn install`.
However, the changes I made in the code are not played back locally...

I even can do

`yarn add https://github.com/Stophface/react-native-maps-0.20.1.git` or `yarn add https://github.com/Stophface/react-native-maps-0.20.1.git#refator-1` and the files I created are not there.

It works with `npm install https://github.com/Stophface/react-native-maps-0.20.1.git` though.

Why is that? I see the files I created locally online in the repo. When I type `yarn install` they should be installed locally too, right?

Comment: you shouldn't be deleting `node_modules` that's what `.gitignore` is for

Comment: @azium I delete them because I do `yarn install`. That shouldn't harm...

Comment: but for what purpose? usually deleting node_modules is if something is messed up and you want a fresh slate

Comment: @azium Well, something is messed up ;) Thats why I deleted them - Just to make sure that `yarn` completly installs all of them anew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because of the npm cache..
add a tag (ex: v0.0.1) to your commit:

```
git tag v0.0.1
git push origin           // push changes
git push origin --tags    // push tags
```

and in your dependencies write:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^16.3.0-alpha.1",
  "react-native": "0.54.0-rc.3",
  "react-native-maps": "github.com/Stophface/react-native-maps-0.20.1#YOURTAG"
}
```